# Add sequence numbering label to google map marker in android

Tags: android, android-mapview, google-maps-markers

How to dynamically add sequence numbers to the markers in android google map with the same marker png?

I have traveled 10 places . I want to show the markers at start point. the markers will have sequence number 1,2,3,.... . How can i do tht ?

This should not be different pngs . I want to use 1 png and the numbers say 1-10 will be printed on the markers.

Well one more thing : The digits will have different colors and fonts as well.

Answer (score 0):

Will you be adding the markers by touching the screen? or will they appear once you've reached that point. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview show how to place markers and the image to go with it. And here is an example project https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Maps/NooYawk which explains how to display multiple markers

Comment: I've already done with showing multiple markers , but I want to place the numbering to the markers.

Comment: Are you using OverlayItem for each marker? if so you can do this: OverlayItem overlayitemmarker1 = new OverlayItem(marker1, "1", "");